# Receive and control serial device data in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a serial device which sends me data at the baudrate of 38400 and i get it like this `?@D00014C000 000`. I can see data comes in on a ritchtextbox but what im trying to do is to use some characters from the string in a list box. 
For example i want characters "14C" appears in the listbox3. I tried the substring and mid function but listbox lidnt work properly and losses characters or confuse them . Here is my code. Any suggestions please??

```
 Imports System
 Imports System.ComponentModel
 Imports System.Threading
 Imports System.IO.Ports

 Public Class frmMain
 Dim myPort As Array
 Delegate Sub SetTextCallback(ByVal [text] As String)



Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    ReceivedText(SerialPort1.ReadExisting())

End Sub

Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String)
    If Me.rtbReceived.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText)
        Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})

    Else
        Me.rtbReceived.Text &= [text]
          Dim fine As String = Mid([text], 7, 3)
        Dim list As Integer = ListBox3.Items.Add(fine)
    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

Here is[PICTURE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM9mV.png) what happens 
[Picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUCwd.png)

Comment: ReadExisting() is a standard bug, you must ensure you get the entire response from the SerialPort before you have any hope of Mid() working correctly.  The protocol that the device uses is not obvious, but good odds that ReadLine() works.  If not then count off the characters.

Comment: With ReadEXisting RitchTextBox fills with data. Looks worknig fine.I replace it with ReadLine but nothing comes in... Is there any way to get the HEX format of the message? I think it will be more easy to handle it cause of the spaces between its data

Comment: https://www.stalkerradar.com/sportsradar/documents/011-0093-00_Pro_II_operator_manual.pdf   page 26 bE format is the setting of my device

Comment: What Hans means is that the DataReceived event may be called with just part of the string.  You'll eventually get the whole thing, but possibly as little as one character at a time.  Try appending some other charcter to rtbReceived.Text each time to see. You may have to just keep track of that characters as you get them and then process everything when you get the newline (or however it indicates end of message)